# Do chilled enemies count as slowed?

Tags: diablo-iv

I have attacks that "chill" enemies and I have stuff that triggers when I hit a "slowed" enemy. Do chilled enemies count as "slow"? And what if I have the passive that says "chilled enemies are slowed 10% more", will it then count as slowed?

Comment: I'd expect "chill" to "slow" as typical game mechanic. Also, I guess you did answer your own question with "chilled enemies are slowed 10% **more**". Why do you think it doesn't slow?

Comment: @ChrᴉzremembersMonica My inner rules lawyer says: "something is only `slowed` if something applies the `slowed` condition to it", so I expect `chilled` to not automatically mean `slowed`, especially since the game does have other things that do apply `slowed` directly. But on the other hand some places in the game, like that "slowed 10% MORE" I mentioned, suggest otherwise -  hence this question.

Comment: This wording makes me wonder if the bonus slow is added additively or multiplicatively.

Comment: I found most key words or verbs are underlined and when hovering an item, show up at the bottom. So keep an eye out for Chill and Slowed in June!

Comment: On previous games, iirc, chill used to slow move speed and attack speed, whereas slow affected only move speed. [Here](http://www.vhpg.com/diablo-4-slowed/) is stated that "Chill is a special form of Slow", so they should count as a similar status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Chilled" and "Slowed" are [different status effects](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/402258/21177). (To be clear, "Slowed" wasn't in the beta but does appear capitalized as a status effect on legendary affixes.) So it is possible to be "Slowed" without being "Chilled" but all "Chilled" include some version of slowdown, as both reduce Movement Speed.

If it isn't being invoked as a proper noun ("slowed" not "Slowed"), your example would mean that any Movement Speed decreases are exacerbated by 10%.