# What do Diablo 4's status effects mean?

Tags: diablo-iv

Similar to [D3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/63625/21177), D4 refers to a series of status ailments/effects in item and move descriptions but it's unclear what each of them are and what they do. E.g., what constitutes Vulnerable or Injured or Overpower?

Where can these be found in game and what do they actually mean?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are quite a few keywords, and many are detailed beneath the item which contains them, both in the skill-tree and on legendary items.

[image: Keyword tooltip]

Here is a list lifted from https://mobalytics.gg/blog/diablo-4/status-effects/

---

**Barrier**
Barriers create a temporary layer of shield that absorbs damage from all sources.

**Berserking**
Grants 25% increased damage and 30% increased Movement Speed.

**Bleeding/Poison**
Targets that are Bleeding or Poisoned are dealt damage over time based on percentage weapon damage.

> Note that:
> Each type of Bleed or Poison applied stacks with itself
> Each type of Bleed or Poison snapshots your damage buffs on the application.
> Each stack of each Bleed or Poison ticks down and expires independently.
> Blood Orbs
> Heals you for 15% of your Maximum Life when picked up.

**Burning**
Targets that are Burning are dealt Fire damage over a period of time (duration defined by its source).

**Chill + Frozen**
Chilled targets have reduced Movement Speed (different things apply different amounts of Chill, represented as a %) if you repeatedly Chill a target, you will Freeze them. When Frozen, targets cannot attack or move.

**Close <-> Distant**
Close refers to targets that are within melee range while Distant refers to targets that are outside of it.

**Crackling Energy**
Crackling Energy is spawned by abilities like the Sorcerer’s Chained Lightning. When picked up, periodic damage is dealt to nearby enemies.

**Crowd Control**
A target that is Crowd-Controlled is affected by Chill, Daze, Fear, Freeze, Immobilize, Knockback, Knockdown, Taunt, Tether, Stun, and/or Slow.

**Daze**
Daze prevents its target from attacking or using skills but allows them to still move.

**Fear**
Feared targets are forced to run away and cannot otherwise move or take action (it can be removed by Immune/Unstoppable effects)

**Fortify**
Fortify is a stacking shield that causes its target to take 10% reduced damage when Foritifed. Fortified refers to when your Fortify’s shield is greater than your current life.

> Example:
> If you have 50 Life and 100 Fortify and you take 10 damage, your Fortify will absorb 1 of that damage (10%) and then you lose 9 health, so you’ll have 41 Life and 99 Fortify.

**Healthy**
Refers to the threshold of having 80% or more Life.

**Hex**
Hexed targets are transformed into harmless creatures for a short time. Their passive effects are nullified and they cannot attack nor move.

**Immune**
Immune prevents all damage and removes/prevents all negative effects.

**Knockback**
Knockback forcibly moves away in the opposite direction from where the target hit originally was.

**Immobilize**
Immobilized targets cannot move (can be removed by Immune/Unstoppable effects).

**Injured/Healthy**
Refers to the threshold of having less than 35% of Life while Healthy refers to having 80% or more Life.

**Lucky Hit**
Activates Lucky Hit effects when a Lucky Hit is landed. It’s fixed on the ability and only improves the base% of the ability.

**Overpower**
Overpowering deals bonus damage based on the sum of your current Life and Fortified Life.
It applies to every hit for both AoE and multi-hit abilities. It doesn’t scale with other stats.

**Slow**
Slow causes its target to have reduced movement speed (based on $ defined by its source).

**Stealth**
The Stealth effect prevents its target from being directly targeted by enemies but they can still be hit (such as by an AoE or projectile). Upon taking damage or using an attack, Stealth will be instantly removed.

**Stun**
Stun causes its target to be unable to move, use skills, or attack.

**Taunt**
Taunt forces a target to switch aggro to target the caster.

**Tether**
Tether prevents its target from moving out of its radius. It can be removed by Immune/Unstoppable or if the Tethered target dies.

**Thorns**
A target with Thorns deals damage to its attacks when hit by direct attacks (does not apply to DoTs).

> Note:
> It does not scale off of weapon damage, but rather, it scales off your other stats. (Damage to close, damage to far, damage to CC’d, etc).
> Protection Shrines and Dodge prevents Thorns from proccing.
> They cannot Crit and they do not count as direct damage.

**Unstoppable**
Unstoppable prevents and removes all control-impairing effects (such as Daze, Slow, Freeze, etc).

**Vulnerable**
Vulnerable targets take 20% increased damage (can be increased by gear).

Answer (score 2):

If there is an Underlined keyword there should be an explanation of said effect under the main tooltip-window.

I couldn't find a good screenshot of it, but this video timestamp show how it looks

[image: Injured characters have less than 35% of their life]

There **Injured** is the underlined keyword and the Explanations states *"Injured characters have less than 35% of their life."*